# How to continue printing without the computer?

Tags: cups, printing

Using cups (ipp://printername) and a brother wifi printer with 256mb internal memory I want to know how I can continue to print after I shutdown my computer (arch linux)?

Currently a print job is paused upon going to standbye and continues on system resume.

Comment: I think the implication from the 256MB memory is that the printer should be able to handle spooling itself

Comment: Could be... I just didn't find any references in Brother sites for that :-) They only seem to refer to OS spoolers. Admittedly I'm not doing any deep digging into their resources.

Comment: If this is a laser printer then a lot of that 256Mb memory would be used to hold the per-page generated bitmap.  Plus program space (eg postscript stack).  Plus font rendering.  Plus...   It's not typically used for spooling of jobs.   Printers that can spool jobs themselves typically have storage devices attached.

Comment: My network-attached laser printer only has 128MiB of RAM, but it manages to spool jobs just fine.

Comment: In my experience network printers (such as those with WiFi) have some form of print server built in. The memory is usually irrelevant. However I _believe_ this is made more complex by the ability to begin printing before the whole job is received. I could not rule out the idea CUPS is holding pages back. But I have zero evidence for any such behaviour.

Comment: To save people guessing could you add ([edit]) the exact printer model?

Comment: Re-phrasing my poorly written comment... this depends on the printer model. If it has an internal spooler, it can continue print jobs after the system feeding it is shut down; if the system is so configured. [Here's](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSPrintQueues#The_device-uri_for_a_Networked_Printer) some information from Debian regarding CUPS and network printers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it, is to setup a print-server - a physical computer which would have a direct connection to the printer and will keep the print job queue.

You will send your pages from the work computer to the print-server and then you can shut down your work computer. The print-server will take care of the queue. Of course, the print-server itself should not be shut down...

256mb is almost nothing. The printer is receiving a postscript (PS) stream - a standard language of multiple printers (including Brother). And postscript is not a very compact format.

You can see what is in the stream by using tools like `pdf2ps` or `tiff2ps`. Just convert your small .pdf into .ps and be amazed.